# How can i use the function ng-click in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a div with pictures who change every 9 seconds, i want to keep it but i want to change the picture when user click on. I think the most easy is to use the ng-click function, but i don't know how 
My code : 
In the HTLM :

```
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 session fondbleuSession">
                      <div>
                        <div ng-controller="eventCtrl">
                          <div ng-repeat="data in event" ng-if="data.id == actualSession">
                            <div class="sessionTxt">
                                <h1>{{data.title}} </h1>
                              <p>{{data.description}} </p>
                            </div>
<!-- ng-click here ? -->   <a ng-href="{{data.url}}" class="sessionImg" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{data.src}})'}" >
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </slider>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

And 
In eventCtrl

```
app.controller('eventCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

  $scope.actualSession = 0;
  var sessionLength = 0;

  // INFORMATION GENERAL EVENT
  // id = reference de l'image pour l'ordre de passage (+1 a chaque nouveau slide ajouté)
  // title = titre de l'event
  // description = resume rapide de l'event
  // src = adresse de l'image
  // url = lien de redirection vers article/sharepoint...

  $scope.event = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Site Events",
      "description": "",
      "src": "images/index/event/Photo1.jpg",
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Site Events",
      "description": "",
      "src": "images/index/event/Photo2.jpg",
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Site Events",
      "description": "",
      "src": "images/index/event/Photo3.jpg",
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Site Events",
      "description": "",
      "src": "images/index/event/Photo4.jpg",
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "Site Events",
      "description": "",
      "src": "images/index/event/Photo5.jpg",
      "url": ""
    }
  ];

  sessionLength = _.size($scope.event);


  $interval(function() {
    $scope.actualSession = $scope.actualSession + 1;
    if ($scope.actualSession == sessionLength) {

      $scope.actualSession = 0;
    }
  }, 9000);   //timer switch event (1000 = 1 seconde)

})
```

And i don't know if it's possible to have this two function : change the picture automatically after x seconds and change the picture when the user click. 
Furthermore, i don't know who to go to the first picture when we come on the last picture
Thank you very much and have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wraping a div around the anchor tag and use ng-click there, hopefully it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change the actionSession variable, it should be straightforward:

```
ng-click="ctrl.someFunc()"
```

Then in the controller:

```
someFunc() {
  $scope.actualSession = $scope.actualSession === sessionLength - 1 ? 0 : $scope.actualSession++;
}
```